# Route to Edit a Specific Path based on Variables - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In the application which I am building, connectors can be made with other sides. These connectors can have different types. This is handled in for example a create routing like:

```
return redirect()->route('connector.'.$connector->type.'.create', $connector->id);
```

I am now trying to generate an edit page, where the user first is able to edit the general information but then has to be redirected to the specific type. The route redirect which I have for this is:

```
return redirect()->route('connector.'.$connector->type.'.edit', $connector->id);
// --> Missing required parameters for [Route: connector.getconnector.edit] [URI: connector/{connector}/getconnector/{getconnector}/edit].
```

route files:

```
Route::resource('connector.reportconnector', 'ReportconnectorController');  
Route::resource('connector.getconnector', 'GetconnectorController');
```

But this route isn't working... When I edit the URL to: `connector/4/getconnector/getconnector/edit`, the page which I would want is generated. But this URL is not how I want it to be. How could I get a : `connector/{id}/{type}/edit` route formatted?

Comment: Route::get('connector/{id}/{type}/edit', 'ReportconnectorController@edit'); Break the routes into as many as you need. Route::resource gives you routes for: index, edit, update, destory with edit and update having only one parameter or use this Route::resource('user', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'user' => 'admin_user'
]]);  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

Comment: Well, it's the convention laravel follows. When you have nested resource routes, it will be in this format - `connector/{connector}/getconnector/{getconnector}/edit`. If you want custom ones, you have to write that all yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Indra! This worked and looks cleaner :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Route::get(); as solution, you have to define for all of others( `index, create, store, show, edit, update, delete` ) OR your route will keep working in its own way.

You don't need to define all with Route::get() only for `edit`.
You can use like this.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'connector'], function()
{
  Route::resource('getconnector', 'GetconnectorController',  ['except' => ['edit']]); //this won't call the edit

  //So, For edit
  Route::get('{id}/{type}/edit',[
    'as' => 'connector.getconnector.edit', 
    'uses' => 'GetconnectorController@create'
    ]);

  //Others Under connector

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! This code is working and I like the URL!